# How to find list of files names with locations under given directory with exact pattern matching with recursive search with linux command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working on a Linux script where I am stuck with listing all the files under a given directory (with recursive match).

Code:

```sh
find /* -type f -exec grep -l 'FY10' {} \;
```

It is listing all the file names which start with `FY`, like `FY10`, `FY11` so on.  I need only `FY10` files locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey you are doing long route.

```
find <base path> -type f -name FY10*
```

with `-name` you can give pattern which will take care of search no need to do exec grep.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your command slightly:

```sh
find . -name 'FY10*' -type f
```

This uses the currect directory as starting directory and searches recursively for a file starting with name `FY10`.

Using `-exec grep` is not needed in this case, since the `find` command can automatically search only for files with a given pattern using the `-name` option.